# My app can't send to Firebase the same data structure more than once

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm trying to replicate this data structure each time an user send a message in my chatApp:

```
{
   entries: {
      users: {
         "twitter username": {
            "unique key assigned by firebase": {
               name: "twitter username",
               text: "whatever which user writes"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So I tried this:

```
var entryRef = new Firebase('https://ranchat.firebaseio.com:443/entries/users/');
var messagesRef = entryRef.child(name);

// When the user presses enter on the message input, write the message to firebase.
$('#messageInput').keypress(function (e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
  // You shouldn't allow an empty entry
  var text = $('#messageInput').val();
  messagesRef.push({name:name, text:text});
  $('#messageInput').val('');
}
});
```

([Here is the whole code of my app](http://codeshare.io/okJ5g))

But messages just are send to firebase once. That is I can write a message on `<input>`, press *Enter* and send it to Firebase ([the data appear in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bXwE.jpg)), but If I want to repeat the same action the data won't appear in it. Due to the users must be logged in with twitter if they want to send messages, I tried to send data from other session (logged in with other twitter account) but it didn't work; after the first message nobody can send data, neither the same user nor a different one.

In the moment when I try to send another message to Firebase, I receive this error in the JS console:

```
"FIREBASE WARNING: set at /entries/users/jobsamuel/-JHXOGvd2Gw1Z8UAZ5X8 failed: permission_denied "
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or what I'm just not doing.

Comment: Is that the whole code? You're missing a closing function brace in the keypress method. Maybe post a jsfiddle with the whole example?

Comment: Yes @Anant, it is the code that I'm using to send comments in my app. I just fixed the missed closing function brace; it was a typo.
And here is the whole script: http://codeshare.io/okJ5g

Comment: Why do you have :443 in your Firebase URL? What does "nobody can send a message" mean? Is there an error in the JS console? Does the request fail? Does the data appear in Firebase if you visit Forge? Are you simply having trouble reading the data back?

Comment: Hi @Kato, I added in the post more details about my problem (the meaning of "nobody can send a message" and the JS error). Furthermore, the :443 appears in my Firebase URL since the beginning; I downloaded a copy of Firebase Examples ($ git clone http://github.com/firebase/examples) and it came with that number. Because of it was working perfectly I didn't change anything. Sadly, when I added **/entries/users/** to the URL the problems started. In other hand, I haven't had any issue reading data back; I can read the only message that I can send to Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified `data.exists()` validation in the security rules of my Firebase Forge and it works:

```
{
"rules": {
".read": true,
"$comment": {
  ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.child('twitter_id').val() == auth.id"
   }
 }
}
```

*The problem was the **!***. When I copied the auth payload for Firebase Simple Login (Twitter) I didn't realize the possible repercussions. Now, with this rules the data is being sent as I want:

```
{
"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": "data.exists() && newData.child('twitter_id').val() == auth.id"
  }
}
```

—

But not all it's perfect. I don't understand two things.

The **first** one: with the new rules I can't send data to Firebase if the [root directory is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2M0U.jpg). I just need to `.push()` or `.set()` something before it.

The **second** one: I need to put **:** after the **.com** in my Firebase reference; the data isn't being sent if I won't put **:**  and I don't know why.

```
var entryRef = new Firebase('https://ranchat.firebaseio.com:/entries/');
var messagesRef = entryRef.child(name).child('messages');

// When the user presses enter on the message input, write the message to firebase.
$('#messageInput').keypress(function (e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
  // You shouldn't allow an empty entry
  var text = $('#messageInput').val();
  messagesRef.push({name:name, text:text});
  $('#messageInput').val('');
  }
});
```

Well... by the moment, I think I'm fine. Thanks for your help!